# Product representation of $\sin z - z \cos z$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, entire-functions

I came across the following question on an exam:

Let $f(z) = \sin z - z \cos z$ be an analytic function on the entire complex plane. Prove that 
$$f(z) = \frac{z^3}{3} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \frac{z}{\lambda_i})$$
where $\lambda_i$ is a sequence of nonzero complex numbers satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2} < \infty$

Well, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are genus 1 functions so that $f$ is as well, so it almost makes sense that we should have such a representation, since the zeroes of $f$ must have the requested growth constraint. However, this only gives us that 
$$f(z) = e^{az + b} z^3\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - \frac{z}{\lambda_i})$$
So we still need to prove that $a = 0$ and $b = \log 1/3$.

I don't really know how to do this. I looked in Ahlfors at one example of computing this standard product representation of a genus 1 trigonometric function which was shown not to require the exponential factor, but it seemed very involved and ad hoc.

Any thoughts? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From the product series in terms of $a,b$,
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z^3}=e^b$$

The left hand side can be evaluated directly, and thus the value of $b$ is obtained.

Similarly,

$$-a=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac 1z \ln \bigg(e^b \frac{z^3}{f(z)}\prod^\infty_{i=1}\left(1-\frac z{\lambda_i}\right)\bigg)$$